# Function was not defined in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, perl

I have two script files - one is perl-cgi and the other is javascript. Inside the cgi script I have written the Javascript function for retrieving data from a text file (using ajax). I then pass the contents of the data into another function called `main_function()`. This writes into the javascript file (`seq_new.js`). When I load the page, the console.log reports `main_function` was not defined. Then I refresh the page and the result displays. I don't know why it behaves this way.

The Perl script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";
use CGI;

my $a= new CGI;
my $processId = $a->param("processId");
.
.
my $file_path = "/$processId/$file_name[1]";
print <<HTML;
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>RepEx - Result</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
file_load("$file_path","$filename");

function file_load(f1,f2)
{
    var fileNm = f2;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 
        {
            var pt = xhttp.responseText;
            main_function(pt,fileNm,"$file_path",$file_cnt,"$head_st");
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", f1, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src='/seq_new.js'> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My javascript file contains this:

```
function  main_function (a,file_seq,main_file,fle_cnt,header_set)
{
   .
   ..
}
```

**The problem I am encountering**

Loading the page for the first time, the `console.log` reports that the `main_function` was not defined and no results are displayed. After refreshing the page (by pressing F5 or clicking the reload button), the result is displayed.

Comment: Which is the JS file? src="/min.js" or src='/seq_new.js' ? and why is src='/seq_new.js' not in the head too? Do you perhaps have document.write in one of them?

Comment: Try calling the function once the page has loaded. In jQuery you can do it by `$(document).ready( function() {...});`

Comment: @mplungjan `seq_new.js` file contain the `main_function`. I put the whole thing into the header but the ajax calling also not working so I put the `seq_new.js` inside the body. `min.js` is a jquery file

Comment: @ChankeyPathak Ya I did it. I did also `window.onload` but it is also the same thing as I mentioned in my post.

Comment: Wrap the `file_load` method under `$(document).ready` and put `seq_new.js` in header (just below `min.js`)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qrBUcEfE